# getElementsByClassName onclick with toggle does not work

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle, getelementsbyclassname

getElementsByClassName does not work. Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>').on("click",function(){
 
       if( document.getElementsByClassName('sub-nav').style.display == 'block' )
       document.getElementsByClassName('sub-nav').style.display = "none";

       $(haid<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>).toggle();
       $(haid<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>).siblings().find(".sub-nav").hide();
      });
});
```

I have separate buttons with unique generated ID and I want to search them by class.
What I am trying to do is when button A is clicked the button B to hide.
The toggle does not function because it cannot find the unique ID for the other button.

if getElementsByClassName finds that there is display:block just to replace it with display:none; and go on with the opening of the clicked button.

Comment: Is `haid` a variable? Just wondering, because you don't have quotes in your selectors: `$(haid<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>)`. Also, why mix vanilla JS and JQuery? I feel you'd be better off using a JQuery class selector, rather than `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @Santi 'haid' is an ID.

Comment: If haid is an ID, then you must select it by doing `$("#haid<?php ... ?>")` - notice the `#` and the quotes.

Comment: @Andrew Li i cannot find duplicates

Comment: I just linked one.

Comment: @Santi the haid function is working. It is to toggle the div to show.
the getElementsByClassName does not

Comment: Why are you mixing javascript and Jquery? Instead getElementsByClassName use $(".name").css("property","value"); or whatever

Comment: @Cgdl tried but still does not work 
`if($(".sub-nav").css("display","block"))
 $(".sub-nav").css("display","none");`

Comment: I'm just saying that you should be consistent in your code with either Jquery or Javascript beacuse mixing it causes you reading troubles

Comment: @Cgdl Thank you! I will brainstorm how to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

i did it. Thank you guys!

```js
 if($(".sub-nav").css("display","block")) {
  $(".sub-nav").css("display","none");
  } else {
  $(".sub-nav").css("display","block");}
```